# Mixing jqGrid and bootstrap with inline editing

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

Subject pretty much says it all....

Mixing jqGrid definition with Twitter bootstrap and I've got issues with the widget sizes on a row in-line edit.

I examined the CSS in Chrome and see that the row has the following CSS styles applied to it:

```
ui-widget-content
jqgrow
ui-row-tlr
ui-state-highlight
```

The widgets themselves, despite being in columns defined at 100px by the grid itself, are being rendered with widths like 260px sending.  Similar issues with text area widgets in the in-line.

I reviewed the  element in Chrome and spotted a bunch of conflicts between the two CSS files (no big surprise), but nothing that was immediately obvious in how it would define these widget widths.

Conflicts:

[image]

None of them jump out at me.  Any suggestions on how to get these inline edit widgets under control?  I think once that's done I'm good to go...

Thanks!

Comment: Nobody else had issues merging jqGrid and bootstrap with edits, eh?

Answer (score 0):

add this css..
`td[role=gridcell] input {padding: 0px !important; width : 98%}`

Comment: Gave it a shot.  Didn't help.  Still ending up with widgets 200% the width of my column :-/